# Can't access Node-Red server running on Beaglebone

Tags: node.js, beagleboneblack, node-red

I've been trying to run NODE-Red on my Beaglebone black with limited success. I followed the guide posted here: http://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2015/07/16/ti-cc2650stk-simplelink-iot-sensortag--node-red-on-beaglebone-black#comment-67139

And was able to successfully install NODE-Red on my BBB. When I try to run it, however, Node-Red will start and give me a message saying server now running at some IP address, and when I try and access that IP address using chrome, it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSD. I've also tried accessing it using https://beaglebone.local:1880 and get the error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. According to Node-Red's website and the guide I linked to above, node red should be working, however, I cannot seem to activate it. I'm quite certain that my beaglebone has internet access so I doubt that is an issue. If anyone has encountered this problem, or knows how to fix it, I would be greatly appreciative of any advice.

Comment: have you tried the ip address #? eg. https://123.123.123.123:1880/red ?

Comment: Ya I've tried that. That method gives the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Which IP address did you try? Node-RED logs 127.0.0.1 on startup because that's the local machine - if you're running on laptop that makes sense. The ifconfig command will tell you your real ip address.

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the beaglebone?  iptables -L will show you